# I'm making a snake game and keep getting this error _tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "704x772+288.0+14.0" what should I do?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm coding a snake game in python and I'm at the point where the food should show up on the screen but I am getting this error:

return self.tk.call('wm', 'geometry', self._w, newGeometry)
_tkinter.TclError: bad geometry specifier "704x772+288.0+14.0"

```
import random
GAME_WIDTH = 700
GAME_HEIGHT = 700
SPEED = 50
SPACE_SIZE = 50
BODY_PARTS = 3
SNAKE_COLOUR = "#00FF00"
FOOD_COLOUR = "#FF0000"
BACKGROUND_COLOUR = "#000000"
class snake:
    pass
class food:
    def __init__(self):
        x = random.randint(0, (GAME_WIDTH /SPACE_SIZE-1)) * SPACE_SIZE
        y = random.randint(0, (GAME_HEIGHT / SPACE_SIZE - 1)) * SPACE_SIZE
        self.coordinates = [x,y]
        canvas.create_oval(x,y, x + SPACE_SIZE, y + SPACE_SIZE, fill=FOOD_COLOUR, tag="food")
def next_turn():
    pass
def change_direction(new_direction):
    pass
def check_collisions():
    pass
def game_over():
    pass
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Snake Game")
score = 0
direction = 'down'
label = Label(window, text="Score:{}".format(score), font=('consolas', 40))
label.pack()
canvas = Canvas(window, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOUR, height=GAME_HEIGHT, width=GAME_WIDTH)
canvas.pack()
window.update()
window_width: int = window.winfo_width()
window_height = window.winfo_height()
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()
x = int(screen_width/2) - (window_width/2)
y = int(screen_height/2) - (window_height/2)
window.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x}+{y}")
snake = Snake()
food = Food()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: window.geometry('200x150')

Comment: You have a decimal point in your geometry specification, which is what makes it invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `window_width/2` with something that produces an int, e.g. `window_width//2`. Do it likewise for `window_height/2`.

This will remove the offending `.0` from the geometry.